# No consigo ordenar una selección con EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Estoy intentando obtener los distintos años en los que tengo ofertas y para ellos laquery SQL es esta tan sencilla

[image: T-SQL]

Pero cuando la traslado al contexto de EF Core tal que asi

```
return await _context.Ofertas.OrderBy(o=>o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum).Select(o => o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum.Year).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

El resultado no me sale ordenado

```
[2021,2022,2016,2019,2020,2017,2018,2015]
```

Alguna idea, por favor?

Salu2

Comment: Hola, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
var listaAnnos = (from o in _context.Ofertas
                  select o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum.Year).
                  Distinct().OrderBy(y => y).ToListAsync();
```

Haces una **consulta Linq** y obtienes primero los años de cada fecha, posteriormente eliminas los duplicados y finalmente ordenas los años ascendentemente, obteniendo como resultado un lista de números enteros.

Comment: Hola. Cuando intento ejecutar esto el orderby no me deja ejecutarlo sin argumentos pero si intento indicarle el campo en una expresión Lambda tal que OrderBy(o=>o....aqui no me muestra los campos. No se si estamos mezclando Lino to SQL con Line to Entities o algo así

Comment: @kintela revisa ahora lo nuevo que puse

Comment: Deberias primero hacer el select y despues el orderby en la consulta, prueba de esa manera, es decir:
    return await _context.Ofertas.Select(o => o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum.Year).OrderBy(o=>o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum).Distinct().ToListAsync();

Comment: @MichaelRipoll es exactamente lo mismo que tengo yo pero de otra forma

Comment: Ah si, es que respondí a tu respuesta y no a la publicación general, que pena, era mostrándole la línea según el contexto que el ya esta utilizando, y que quizá no se lo esta ordenando porque cuando hace un select ps esta armando una nueva lista con los datos que necesita y el orderby esta detrás de ese select, por eso no lo aplica en el resultado de la consulta, nuevamente disculpa amigo.

Comment: @MichaelRipoll cuando intento tu sentencia me da error al intentar ordenar por FechaPresentacion me dice que "int" no contiene una definición para "FechaPresentacion" ni un metodo de extension accesible "FechaPresentacion" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "int". No lo entiendo tampoco la verdad. Gracias y un saludo

Comment: @Japv la ultima version que me has mandado me devuelve los años ordenados muchas gracias y un saludo

Comment: @kintela si la respuesta resolvio tu problema te agradeceria que la marcaras como aceptada y dieras tu voto, gracias